# Catalina, randomly crashes on login screen after sleep

Tags: macos, catalina

Since I updated to macOS Catalina - 10.15.0, I'm experiencing random "crashes" on the login screen after I wake my MBP (2019) up. I just can't do anything, I see the login screen, but I'm not able to do anything, it just displays the spinning wheel cursor after a few secs.

Updated to 10.15.1 and 10.15.2, with no success.

Here's some logs:

```
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2020-01-08 09:33:57 +0100 :2   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1

Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: (null)
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Start                 powerd process is started                                                             
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using AC(Charge: 99)          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 218(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008000 [System: PrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 129(powerd) Created InternalPreventDisplaySleep "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 00:00:00  id:0x0x1000008001 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 218(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008000 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 231(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008002 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 231(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008002 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 235(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008003 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 235(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008003 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 241(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008004 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 241(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008004 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 253(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008005 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:40 +0100 Assertions            PID 253(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008005 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:05:48 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2020-01-08 13:05:58 +0100 Assertions            PID 176(hidd) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000006aa name:NULL product:Magic Mouse 2 eventType:17" 00:00:00  id:0x0x90000813d [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:06:19 +0100 Assertions            PID 1621(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x5000081b8 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:06:19 +0100 Assertions            PID 1621(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x5000081b8 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:06:25 +0100 Assertions            PID 1689(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x5000081c7 [System: PrevDisp DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:06:25 +0100 Assertions            PID 1689(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x5000081c7 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-08 13:06:40 +0100 Notification          Next immediate inactivity window start:'2020-01-08 13:00:00 +0100' end:'2020-01-08 15:45:00 +0100'
```

I've seen a lot of similar issues, but not that particular one. It's kinda annoying, any idea to solve this?

**Edit:**

*I can't provide logs for this, or anything, but I noticed that it happens a lot more when I'm running web dev tools (Webpack, RN packager and that kind of stuff which are basically local NodeJS servers) that I don't kill before the computer goes to sleep.*

Comment: Did you check your MBP by booting up in Safe  Mode?

Comment: Check for what?

Comment: Did you upgrade in place from an earlier version (Mojave, High Sierra, etc.)?  Or, did you do a clean install, meaning you wiped the drive and installed Catalina like it was a new computer?  Now, before you go and re-install macOS, try booting from [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  Also, if you want to try a clean installation, don't wipe your internal drive (yet).  Use an external USB drive (a 32 GB flash is fine) and boot from that (hold Opt when turning on).  If the problem goes away, then it's your install.

Comment: Same happen to me on 10.15.2 and 10.15.3 when only running Mail, Safari, Finder and Preview. I looked up the Apple forum and it seems there are hundreds having the same issue/questions

Comment: I didn't experience this issue for a few days now... The only thing I did is : install Sequel Pro. I don't see how this could be related, but well, you know.

Answer (score 2):

I had this start happening the day following my upgrade to Catalina. For me it turns out that I had cron jobs piling up.  I had 3 entries in my crontab for Magento from a project I worked on a couple years ago.  Apparently cron has been [deprecated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/why-is-cron-being-deprecated) for quite a while now and it seems that since I upgraded to Catalina, the cron jobs would not exit after running, causing the processes to pile up, consuming resources.

I solved my problem by deleting my crontab since I no longer needed these jobs to run.  I used `crontab -r` to delete the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

NVRAM (nonvolatile random-access memory) is a small amount of memory that your Mac uses to store certain settings and access them quickly. PRAM (Parameter RAM) stores similar information, and the steps for resetting NVRAM and PRAM are the same.

Settings that can be stored in NVRAM include sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, time zone, and recent kernel panic information. The settings stored in NVRAM depend on your Mac and the devices that you're using with your Mac.

If you experience issues related to these settings or others, resetting NVRAM might help.

**How to reset NVRAM:**

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together:
 <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

More detail from the Offical [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, but how is it related to my issue?

Comment: Well, it doesn't do the trick. I updated to 10.15.3 too, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've tried resetting NVRAM, the only practical next step is to reinstall macOS, before doing this you need to take a backup.

There are two ways to go about this:

1. Reinstall over the top, this should maintain files and settings and replace the operating system, this may work, if it doesn't then...
2. Clean install and re-setup your Mac.

If neither of these steps work then you'll need to take it in for hardware service, but it seems unlikely the issue is with hardware.