# Using launchd to clear bash history?

Tags: bash, script, launchd, history

> Clarification: Am not looking to destroy `history`, am looking for means
> to periodically purge it via `launchd` for security purposes

Have been using `cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history` to clear bash history as have seen in many *nix conversations as the most effective way to do so.

So I put it into a shell script that runs in `launchd`, yet after some time I've come to realize though it runs it's not clearing history.

Is it possible to clear bash history this way via bash script or can it only be done manually as a user? Perhaps I need to run the command directly in the .plist and not via a bash script?

Note: I have other scripts running correctly via launchd so question is strictly about being able to clear history via an agent

Thank you

> Update: Found this cool site that helps generate `launchd` scripts if
> this helps anyone. Cannot vouch for it but it's much easier than
> hacking XML.
> It seems to use `sh -c` for all commands though, so not sure why that is.
>
> launchd plist generator
> http://launched.zerowidth.com/

Comment: Please add the plist and the script to the question.

Comment: FWIW: If you're keen on using `launchd`, you should take a look at [`LaunchControl`](https://soma-zone.com/). It's not free, but it's *brilliant*, and well worth the modest price. After using it for a few weeks, you'll realize that `launchd` actually is useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `bash` history consists of two "histories", not one. One of these histories is stored in a file - its size/depth is governed by the parameter `HISTFILESIZE`. The other history is cached in memory - its size is governed by the parameter `HISTSIZE`.

You can check the sizes/depth of your histories:

```bsh
$ echo $HISTFILESIZE 
$ echo $HISTSIZE
```

The reason for two histories is that one is associated with **each** shell session (`HISTSIZE`), while the other history is a file `~/.bash_history` that is "permanent", and eventually receives the session histories when they overrun their max depth, or when the session is terminated. That's a bit complicated to explain, and the picture below may help make the relationship between these two histories clear.

But back to your objective:

Rather than taking steps to delete your history, you could simply set `HISTSIZE`
and `HISTFILESIZE` to zero in `~/.bashrc`:

```
HISTSIZE=0
HISTFILESIZE=0
```

If that's not what you want, you can certainly delete the history file periodically, but know that doesn't delete the **session history**. Deleting your history file by building a `.plist` file isn't necessary. The `history` command is the tool to use for this job (see `history --help` for details). The following command will delete ***one*** **session history**:

```bsh
$ history -cw
```

Deleting the *contents* from the history file (`~/.bash_history`) is done conventionally:

```bsh
$ > ~/.bash_history
```

You could put one or both of these commands in a `crontab`, but you'll need to ensure the default shell is `bash` as `history` is a *built-in*.

For some related background on the subject of shell history, you could [read this related Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/398534/macos-catalina-terminal-tab-doesnt-remember-its-own-previous-commands/398543#398543). It pertains to `zsh` - not `bash`, but the principles are the same.

[image]

Comment: `crontab` has been deprecated in Mac OS though was using it before and is why am jiggling around with `launchd` again now. Im not looking to wipe history as I definitely use it! It's wanting to purge it periodically -- is there any code that can automatically run when I close a terminal session?

Comment: Ok.. so I see now, if I just set `HISTFILESIZE=0` the file is not generated and I'll still get terminal session history!?

Comment: Ok wow, thanks you've pointed me in the right direction: "When one exits the bash, if there are more than $HISTSIZE number of commands which have been executed in the single bash session, the contents of $HISTFILE will be replaced by the $HISTSIZE number of commands. If there are less than or equal to $HISTSIZE number of commands in the bash session, these commands will be appended to $HISTFILE as long as $HISTFILESIZE permits." -- https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-the-number-of-commands-stored-in-bash-history/

Comment: @iGuest: `cron` hasn't been deprecated AFAIK, but Apple has made it more difficult to use for reasons unclear to me. I can say with certainty that `cron` still works as of Catalina 10.15.6. But IIRC, that required giving `cron` "Full Disk Access" in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access`.

Comment: I was still using it until this week. But officially they've pushed for people to quit it some time ago, since 10.4, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/why-is-cron-being-deprecated

Comment: *"if I just set HISTFILESIZE=0 the file is not generated and I'll still get terminal session history"*  Yes, that's the way it works.

Comment: Re **deprecated**: I think perhaps someone took liberties with the definition of "deprecated". Superseded? Maybe... but if you've ever had to grub out a `.plist` file manually using Apple's documentation, you'll know why this isn't their best move. And [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385216/149366) is accurate.

Comment: @iGuest: And finally (as SE's nagging re "extended discussions" has now begun), the description you've quoted from *geekdiary* is not entirely accurate. When you terminate a session, all of the items in your session history are **eligible** for being appended to the history file. Whether they are or not is a function of how your history options/directives are set up.

Comment: well https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html says "Note: Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of launchd." -- but excellent point it's part of the *nix OS so they can't truly toss it. and yes the plist concept is obnoxious. Thank god we have JSON and HTML5 for the web

Comment: @iGuest: Yes... Apple tells many lies, and they fail horribly at documentation. Ooops!! I've just revealed the *dark side* :)  lol

Answer (score 5):

It seems you've come up with a very convoluted solution to the problem of not wanting a bash_history.

I would advise that instead of periodically clearing the history from launchd, you should simply disable history recording:

```
echo 'set +o history' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Close the terminal tab and open a new one - and your history will no longer be recorded.

Comment: And probably run `rm -f ~/.bash_history` once to remove the old one.

Comment: no these solutions don't work because i DO want to keep history but also want it to clear out for security purposes. Removing the file doesn't allow you to generate new history -- a more elegant solution to your rm is `history -wc` to clear and overwrite the history file. I am looking for a way to automate this sort of action.

Comment: ok thanks, i didn't realize the relationship between the history file and session history. so thats the key as per the other comments here. Thank you